# How do I get both AMD Mobility Radeon hd 4250 and 5650's working in a laptop?

Tags: 12.10, graphics, radeon, fglrx, gpu

My laptop has 2 GPUs inside:

- AMD Mobility Radeon HD 4250
- AMD Mobility Radeon HD 5650

After fresh installing Ubuntu 12.10, I tried installing official drivers, which broke Unity and made it unusable. I tried downgrading `xorg` to 1.12, installing `fglrx-legacy` which gave a black screen after starting Ubuntu and nothing works, including the `tty`.
Looks like `fglrx` includes 5xxx drivers, `fglrx-legacy` 4xxx drivers and I have both cards.

Isn't there any other drivers that support both GPUs?? The laptop is really overheating (79°c) and it used to work normally in older Ubuntus. (12.04, 11.10 as I tried).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same card.It seems to me that this type of configuration is not solved properly as we need to install 2 types of drivers. First of all forget about using 12.10.Whit this card it is recomended to not use above 12.04 and use fglrx legcy due to X.org incompatibility.And after this only your low performance card will work.The proprietary driver is not capable to switch between a legacy chip(4250) and a non legacy chip(5650).Atleast this is what my testing shows so far. I am going to try to install the older driver catalyst 11.5 but i have no idea why it shuld work better then my current catalyst 12.6. other possibility is to use opensource drivers + vgaswitcheroo to manually switch between them but then again the open source driver has terrible power management and the fan will run all the time with high graphics chip temperatures.please report this issue on amd site under the legacy drivers section.